# Locale variables change when launching chef-client

Tags: chef-infra, locale, environment

When running a chef-client on my server, i get a problem when doing a service restart of a c++ binary because of the locale variables.

Before launching chef-client i have my locale:

```
LANG=POSIX
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

The problem is that the locale change when the chef-client is started, it becomes :

```
 LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

and returns to POSIX when the execution is finished.

How I can fix this ? and from where chef-client get his defaults encoding setting ? the binary should run with POSIX (i can fix that by doing an export LC_ALL=POSIX in the init script, but i want to know the root problem)

NB : I didn't have this issue with chef-client 11, i get it once I update to chef-client 12

Comment: Please see [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1210) and a probably related to your question [issue](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3367). Without more details on which OS you're using, how you're calling your program, and which version of Chef, it's impossible to give more advice.

Comment: I'm on a ubuntu 12.04, and the version of Chef-client is 12.4.1 (chef server paquet : 12.0.0-1) the action i run is classic restart of a service.    ` 'execute "restart-toto-service" do
     command "sudo -i -u toto /toto/scripts/service restart"
     action :nothing
end' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant code lives [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/chef-config/lib/chef-config/config.rb#L704-L756).

Basically in Chef 12 we tried to fix the long tail of locale issues caused by improper settings by detecting the system locale. This might not be working correctly for you. You can always set it explicitly on execute resources though via the `environment` property.

Comment: Okey thanks i will do that, so it is the same issue mentioning by @Tensibai. that's why i did not have this probleme with chef 11